# PayPal Payments Standard Discount Issue

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

I use Payments Standard as a payment Method in Magento.

I checkout page I have add a custom discount to my cart and it will work perfectly at cart page.  see the below Image.

[image]

When you move to the checkout page then I also got the discount.

[image]

When I place order and It will redirect to the paypal then I did not get Discount. please see the below Image.

[image]

Please Help me to solve out this issue.

If any body got same issue then help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell PayPal about the discount order total. You can do this by modifying the PayPal cart object that is passed.

Observe the event `paypal_prepare_line_items` (`Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart` line 318)

In your observer, you load the paypal cart as such:

```
$payPalCart = $observer->getPaypalCart();
```

Get your discount amount from the order

```
$order = $payPalCart->getSalesEntity();
$discountAmount = $order->getDiscountAmount();
```

You can then set the discount amount by calling updateTotal()

```
$payPalCart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_DISCOUNT, $discountAmount);
```

And that is it, PayPal will now know about your discount. This should work for standard, advanced, and pro I believe - both express checkout and direct payments.

Comment: Yes @ben It's Working.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the following function in my custom module's observer worked:

```
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function updatePaypalTotal(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {        
        $label = SOME_LABEL;
        $qty = SOME_QTY;
        $feeAmount = SOME_FEE_AMOUNT;
        $itemNumber = SOME_IDENTIFIER_OR_SKU;

        /* @var $cart Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart */
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();

        $cart->addItem($label, $qty, $feeAmount, $itemNumber);

        return $this;
    }
}
```